# Unpacking a python tuple in a python function

Tags: python, function, tuples

Using Visual Studio & http://pythontutor.com/visualize I am unable to get the result for filesize function because of the following Error: TypeError: file_size() takes 1 positional argument but 3 were given. Code below.

```js
#this function stores information about a file, its name, its type and its size in bytes.
def file_size(file_info):
    name, file_type, size = file_info
    return("{:.2f}".format(size/1024))

print(file_size('Class Assignment','docx', 17875)) #Should print 17.46
print(file_size('Notes','txt', 496)) #Should print 0.48
print(file_size('Program','py', 1239)) #Should print 1.21
```

I though unpacking (file_info) within the function will override the 1 positional argument but 3 were given error. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: file info is not a tuple, you've passed 3 strings.

Comment: You need just one extra character: `def file_size(*file_info):` if you want to call the function this way.

Answer (score 1):

Currently you are passing three distinct arguments ... pass it instead as **one** argument which is a tuple:

```
print(file_size( ('Class Assignment','docx', 17875) ))
```

Alternatively, you could alter your function declaration to capture distinct arguments into a tuple when called:

```
def file_size(*file_info):
    ...
```

Then calling it as you are is valid.

Answer (score 1):

Put the values into a tuple like this:

```
print(file_size(('Class Assignment','docx', 17875)))
print(file_size(('Notes','txt', 496)))
print(file_size(('Program','py', 1239)))
```

This way you are passing one variable

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the function with one parameter, try assigning the tuple to a variable and pass it in:

```
file_size(*varname)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
def file_size(file_info):
    name, type, size= file_info
    return("{:.2f}".format(size / 1024))
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this.

```
def file_size(file_info):

    (name,file_type,size)  = file_info
    return("{:.2f}".format( size/ 1024))
```

You need to pass `file_info` in a tuple in python.